# Alter how oldfiles are displayed

Tags: external-command, filesystem

Is it possible to "preprocess" the oldfiles list so that it's easier to navigate visually?

As far as I can tell, the contents of the oldfiles list are presented as ordinary absolute paths, but with the user's home directory replaced with `~`. This works well for most cases, but sometimes I'm navigating deep in a directory that's outside of my home directory and it's hard to read the file names.

For example, if I'm editing files in `/tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy` and visit a bunch of files there, they show up as

```
1: /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/h
2: /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/g
3: /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/f
4: /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/e
5: /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/d
6: /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/c
7: /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/b
8: /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/a
```

Using a probably-way-longer-than-necessary perl script I can extract just the filename

`perl -ne 'chomp; @w = split /\s+/; $b = ""; $w[-1] =~ m{/([^/]*)\z} and $b = $1; printf "%s %s %s\n", $w[0], $b, "@w[1..$#w]";'`

When run against the contents of oldfiles list it produces the following:

```
1: h /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/h
2: g /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/g
3: f /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/f
4: e /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/e
5: d /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/d
6: c /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/c
7: b /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/b
8: a /tmp/some/deeply/nested/hierarchy/a
```

Is there a way I can either use my script as a filter ... or define a filter in VimL to change how the oldfiles list is displayed?

Or, ideally, just change some format string somewhere that vim uses.